# Unable to read memory

Tags: c++

I am trying to load shaders from file but getting an error :

[image]

While tying to read a file. These 2 files are in the same file as a whole project, so the path is not needed, right ? Even if i used the whole path from the c:// lvl it does not help - still the same.

That is how I am initializing the constructor of the shader :

```
#include "Chart.h"

Chart::Chart() : shader(new Shader("ChartVertexShader.fs", "ChartFragmentShader.vs"))
{
    setData();
}
```

and then in the Shader as a following [here](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?type=header&code=shader) it keeps giving me the same error. Any one knows what might be wrong ?

Also I have added few lines for checking if file exist : like u can see from screenshot.

```
    std::ifstream ifile(vertexPath);
    std::ifstream ifilee(fragmentPath);
    if (ifile.good()) {
        std::cout << "EXIST" << std::endl;
    }
    if (ifilee.good())
    {
        std::cout << "EXIST" << std::endl;
    }
```

This error occure for both paths,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, _Tiestr is a nullptr so you can't dereference it and see what it points to because its no pointing to anything (valid). Maybe you mixed up your filename extensions. I'm assuming .fs stands for Fragment Shader, but you called it ChartFragmentShader.vs

Comment: @ThunderStorm yeah, thats vertex shader and fragment shader.

Comment: Double and triple check your filepath. You can further check what is the problem by looking at the return values of eof(), fail() and bad(). You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)

Comment: I am keep checking it, but it does not work ;/

Comment: What do eof(), fail() and bad() return?

Comment: @ThunderStorm every thing returned 0 except `fail() = 1`

Comment: Have you tried looking at [perror()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/?kw=perror) or errno right after you created the ifstream object?

Comment: I figure out! I've put an additional `\` before each in the full path. Otherwise it does not work for me. I've tried a lot of ways to read files and it won't let me to do that, even if the file is in the project path.